# Summary of elements from different lists, which are all related to each other

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, numbers

Imagine you've got an instance of List<List> with several entries. For example:

```
List<List<int>> inputLists = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> { 4, 2, 1 },
    new List<int> { 5, 9, 1 },
    new List<int> { 6, 1, 2 },
    new List<int> { 9, 4, 3 },
    new List<int> { 9, 4, 2 }
};
```

I now want to summarize elements in bigger lists if each of them is related to each of them. The result lists should have a minimum amount of 4 elements tho. For the example above our result would be a List<List> with only one entry: { 4, 2, 1, 9 } (sorting irrelevant). Why is that?

Try to form pairs:

- 9 is in the same list as 1 (check second list)
- 9 is in the same list as 2 (check last)
- 9 is in the same list as 4 (check fourth / last)
- 4, 2 and 1 are all in the same list as well (check first; trivial)

Here is my code. I want to apology if it appears brain damaged, I did not get enough sleep lately.

```
internal void Test()
{
    List<List<int>> inputLists = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> { 4, 2, 1 },
    new List<int> { 5, 9, 1 },
    new List<int> { 6, 1, 2 },
    new List<int> { 9, 4, 3 },
    new List<int> { 9, 4, 2 }
};

    foreach (var input in inputLists)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> results = Array.Empty<IEnumerable<int>>();
        input.ForEach(number =>
        {
            //first step: getting all numbers that are related to "number"
            //number is 4 | related ones are: 4, 2, 1, 9, 3
            IEnumerable<int> everyFrickingNumberAppearing = Array.Empty<int>();
            inputLists.Where(inputList => inputList.Contains(number)).ToList()
            .ForEach(inputList =>
            everyFrickingNumberAppearing =   everyFrickingNumberAppearing.Concat(inputList).Distinct()
            );


            var IReallyDontKnowWhatIAmDoing = everyFrickingNumberAppearing
            //trying out every number
            .Where(probablyRelatedNumber => inputLists
            //looking if there is at least one element that
            //appears in at least one list together with "number"
            .Any(list => list.Contains(probablyRelatedNumber) && list.Contains(number)))
            .ToArray();
            //appending all related numbers of "number" to results
            results.Append(IReallyDontKnowWhatIAmDoing);
        });
        //going through results
        results.ToList().ForEach(r =>
        {
            //selecting only nums which appear in every result
            var importantNums = r.Select(num => results.ToList().All(l => l.Contains(num)));
            //print it
            importantNums.ToList().ForEach(n => Console.Write($"{n} "));
            Console.WriteLine();
        });
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, I expected 4 2 1 9 (sorting not relevant) to be the output.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you should structure your logic at least at description. Then, if solution will not appear by itself, maybe issue become clearer. Because for now it is complicated to follow your idea, which is mix of unrelated relations and unpaired pairs of numbers, which you want to relate or pair (by... which criteria?)

Comment: I try to explain it a bit different. We have several small lists and want to summarize those in bigger ones. The criterion is that each element in the list has already appeared as a pair with every other in one of the smaller lists.

Comment: Another example: { 1, 2, 3 }, {4, 5, 1} {4, 2, 5}, {3, 7, 4} would lead to {1, 2, 3, 4} as every pair of those 4 elements appeared in one of the smaller lists.

Comment: I feel it's hard to understand. If this is from a homework or program game, please show the original description. If this is from an actual problem, please describe the problem itself.

Comment: Its not a homework or a game. There is no "original" description. I really dont know how to explain it in another way. You've got several lists. You may find pairs of numbers. A "pair" is defined by two numbers which are in the same list. I want to summarize all numbers which are pairs. The other way around: if we got the result { 1, 2, 3} then our input must have been a bunch of lists with at least one of them containing the pair { 1, 2 }, one of them containg the pair { 2, 3 } and one of them containing the pair { 1, 3 }.

Comment: Let me put it another way, how did this problem come about? Were these number lists suddenly pop out of your mind, and then you suddenly thought that you need to summarize such a set of elements from them?

Comment: If i have lists `[0] {1,2,3}, [1] {1,5,3}, [2] {2,1,5}` then pairs are `[0] {1,2}, [1] {1,3}, [2] {2,3}, [3] {1,5}, [4] {3,5}, [5] {2,5}`. For example, Pair [0] exists only in List [0] (reversed pair {2,1} in List [2] should count or not?). Pair [1] exists in Lists [0] and [1]. QUESTION: what here is your desired output?

Comment: As you see, there is too many unclear moments. Even you with each new comment provide new different info, which "brokes" previous logic. So I again offer you to restructure what you have and rewrite question. Correct question is 50% of solution.

Comment: I dont want to be rude, but I already mentioned several times, that the sorting is unrelevant. That means that you dont have to consider a reversed pair as a different one. My desired output are pairs with  length > 4. In your given example the wanted result would be an empty list. If I change your example a little bit

[0] {1, 2, 3, 4, 7}
[1] {1, 5, 3}
[2] {2, 1, 5, 4}

In this case we would get three lists: [0], [2] and a new one: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} because 5 gets in touch with every other element between 1 and 4 (as you see in [1] [2]). I really appreciate your effort btw.

Comment: It's also perfectly fine if you ignore my question if you haven't understood it now. It is not my goal to drive other developers crazy.

Comment: Typo happened: desired output is of course >= 4, as I already mentioned above!

Comment: 5 maybe gets in touch, but I don't. Still can't see logic here. Pair means 2, but you saying "pairs with length > 4", which absolutely pointless. You provide in question lists of 3 numbers in each with desired output, now you saying such lists should produce empty result, and non-empty is possible when list has more than 4... numbers? Or pairs of numbers? Or pairs of numbers when there is at least 5 numbers? Or at least 4 pairs? I'm losing it and see no solution until you can provide full explanation of what you want. "Fine to ignore question" - than why you asking?

Comment: I gave you the full explanation. Sorry for misunderstandings.I am not a native speaker (as you might guess). Last time I'll try to explain: 
When weve got an output, like {1, 3, 5, 9} or whatever then it means that we got a pair of each possible combination (in this case: 1,3 and 1,5 and 1,9 and 3,5 and 3,9 and 5,9) in at least one of our input arrays. The output must be >= 4 OR empty if not enough numbers were found, which seems logical to me because I already mentioned several times, that I'm not interested in outputs with length < 4. The input length of the lists is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us create a `HashSet<(int, int)>` storing each pair of numbers occurring in the same list as value tuple. For sake of simplicity lets store the pairing twice as (x, y) and (y, x). This simplifies the further processing.

```cs
var pairs = new HashSet<(int, int)>();
foreach (var smallList in _inputLists) {
    foreach (int a in smallList) {
        foreach (int b in smallList) {
            if (a != b) {
                pairs.Add((a, b));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since each pair appears twice as (x, y) and (y, x), we can now simply group by one of the items of the tuple (`Item1`) and count how many times it occurs to filter the ones appearing at least 4 times.

```cs
var result = pairs
    .Select(p => p.Item1)
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(g => g.Count() >= 4)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
foreach (var g in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key);
}
```

Prints:

```
1
2
4
9
```

Comment: Thanks for providing help. We are halfway there. Your solution only delivers one possibility, even when there are more lists to return. I think I'll do the rest on my own.